# How do you unittest top level .js of vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I test my Vue.js project with Jest test tool.
For only the coverage, I wish to test top level .js, too.
It passed, but I got the error message below.

How do you test top level .js?

```
console.error node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.js:589
  [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app
console.error node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.js:589
  [Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

  (found in <Root>)
```

#### My main.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from '@/App'
import store from '@/store'
import router from '@/router'

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>',
})
```

#### My main.spec.js:

```js
import main from '@/main'

describe('main.js', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(console, 'log')
    jest.spyOn(console, 'error')
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    console.log.mockRestore()
    console.error.mockRestore()
  })

  it('init', () => {
    expect(console.log).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(console.error).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try to do the following. Should work.

In your *jest.conf.js* file add a setup file.

```
setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/test/unit/setup']
```

Create the *setup.js* and create the div.

```
createAppDiv();
function createAppDiv() {
 var app = document.createElement('div');
 app.setAttribute('id', 'app');
 document.body.appendChild(app);
}
```

Run test

Hope that helps

Comment: Thnx, kimy82! It resolved a half. "Cannot find element: #app" disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Just complementing @kimy82 answer, the error message:

```
You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.
```

This error occurs because the build used for testing is the **runtime** build.
The runtime build doesn't have the template compiler within it.

The best way to solve your problem is to use the `render` function instead of `template` attribute.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  components: { App },
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

As you can see in the vue's [package.json](https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/package.json), the main script is **vue.runtime.common.js**

For bundle size issues the runtime build doesn't have the template compiler.

#### But why?

**A**: If you'r using SFC, .vue files, you are using webpack to bundle your app and run `vue-loader` to transpile the .vue file correctly and this loader compiles the template into a render function and than there is no need for a template compiler in runtime.

Check out other builds from vue: https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/